# How to render or redirect to view by calling the name of the method in slim?

Tags: php, twig, slim

Hi i am developing a webapp where i have user slim framework for routing and twig for frontend templating. I am working on social login module where after authentication an want the user to be redirected to dashboard section. I got stuck at the point of rendering. What i have to do is to call the method named channels.list shown below from another method written below this method:

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app){


$templateData = [
    'pageTitle' => 'Channels'
];

$app->render("routes/channels/list/list.twig", $templateData);

})->name('channels.list');
```

but when i tried calling the channels.list from my login's get request i am getting loader error.

I am calling it in this way from my login request:

```
$app->get('/log-in/:type', function($type) use ($app, $hybridauth) {

if ($type == 'Facebook') {
    $user = callSocial($app, $hybridauth); // function call for social login

    $email = $user->email;
    $displayName = $user->displayName;
    $db = $app->db->users;
    $userData = $db->find(array('email' => $email))->count();

    if ($userData == 0) {
        // insert user segment
        $template = 'channels.list';
        $app->render($app->urlFor($template));
    } else {

        //update the last login time

        $template = 'channels.list';
        $app->redirect($app->urlFor($template));
    }
} else {
    $templateData = [
        'pageTitle' => 'Log In',
        'UI' => [
            'noSidebar' => true
        ]
    ];

    $app->render("routes/log_in/log_in.twig", $templateData);
}
})->name('logIn');
```

Is there any other way to call or method to call. I hope the question got cleared because i an new to slim that uses twig as a templating engine.

**Note:** : I can not call the twig file associated with the channels list view as some pre processing is associated with the php file that renders the twig view.

Comment: You can't do this... `$app->render($app->urlFor($template));` you cannot render a URL.

Comment: Then what supposed to be the method to redirect?

Comment: $app->response->redirect($app->urlFor($template), 301); ... http://docs.slimframework.com/response/helpers/